# Remove only one specific event handler in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I'm writing a small 2D engine that uses Lua to control it.  I've been setting events up in between the Lua and the VB.net for the past little while here.  The problem, I've realized, is that is that I can't seem to remove the events which is screwing up quite a few things (because they are being called when they should be done with).  To fix this, I wanted to add some kind of way to remove the specific event handler.

I know how to add an event handler:

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1Clicked
```

But with this in mind, is their a way to remove a specific event handler in the VB.net?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't explain this very well:

If I have this:

```
public sub setupevent(byval func as LuaFunction)
    AddHandler Me.event_mouseup, Sub(x As Integer, y As Integer)
        func.Call(x, y)
    End Sub
end sub

(Somewhere else)

setupevent(someLuaFunction)
setupevent(someOtherLuaFunction)
setupevent(JustAnotherLuaFunction)
```

Is there a way to remove just one of these event connections on the fly?

Comment: Using a lambda is your problem, you can't remove it.  Do it the old way with a separate method as the event handler and you'll have no problem using RemoveHandler.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please explain on how do do that?

Comment: You need to explain why Markus' answer didn't help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the following statement:

```
RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1Clicked
```

Keep in mind, that it is possible to register the EventHandler more than once. If so, you'll reveive the event as often as you registered the handler. Therefor removing the handler will only remove one registration and you will still receive the button-event.

Edit:
by the way: Your example in your Edit does not look like a standard event handler (sender As object, e As EventArgs)
In general you can add and remove handle using this:

```
Public Sub FirstHandler(sender As object, e As EventArgs)
 ' …
End Sub

Public Sub SecondHandler(sender As object, e As EventArgs)
 ' …
End Sub
```

Somewhere:

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf FirstHandler
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf SecondHandler
RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf FirstHandler
' Only SecondHandler subscribed now
```

You’re using a lambda expression as EventHandler, so you lack on having its specific address to remove it.

Comment: When removing it, which one will it actually remove?  I need to be able to remove a specific one. -- Please see my edit.

Comment: Have you really registered the handler more than once to the **same** Button1Clicked-method? This sounds like an error. You can have multiple handling methods and then you can remove a specific handler by calling RemoveHandler with the address of the handling method (e.g. Button1Clicked) you want to unscribe.